# load php scripts from a mysql database table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql database and in one of the fields I have a bunch of normal html and a php script in the middle of it. When I pull from the database and display the field the php does not render as php, but as html. Was wondering if it is possible to put php scripts in a mysql database field and then have them render as php when pulled onto a web page, and if so how do i do this.

Comment: Why on earth are you doing this?

Comment: It's not a good idea to do this in the first place. Is there really a pressing need to do this, as opposed to storing template data in the database that you then fill in - maybe using an engine like Twig or Smarty?

Comment: Why not make it a separate PHP page and it load with ajax? Storing PHP in your database has no value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have done this before using the eval function.  However, eval is dangerous because if malicious code gets injected it could cause serious harm, so proceed with caution.

What I have done as an alternative is store a class name and parameters in a database and then generate the given class to generate the html and php.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is `eval()`... because when you pull the code from the database it is stored as a string.

**BUT be warned!**...

> The **eval()** language construct is **very dangerous** because it allows execution of arbitrary PHP code. **Its use thus is discouraged**.

Taken straight from the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php).

If you take user input into the database fields, do not use `eval()` as the user can upload malicious scripts into your database.

In fact why do you need to store PHP in the database? This sounds poorly designed and I would strongly encourage you to find another method. Check out [Mustache](https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php) or search for PHP templating engine.

**If you must use `eval()` read about it a lot first**, make sure you understand the security risks.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good idea to do this in the first place - out of security, design and other considerations.

The usual way to do this is called *templating*.

Your HTML code in the database would contain placeholders, say like

```
<h1>Title of this page: {$title}</h1>
<p>Contents: {$contents}</p>
...
```

you would then fill in those placeholders using PHP, after pulling them from the database. There are also full-blown template engines that do the job, e.g. [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) or [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/). (The latter is a bit more light-weight)